# Handle browser close and invalidate session

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using below code for detecting browser close event and then invalidate session. It works fine if directly I click on browser close button.  If I click on some <a href > in the page then window.onbeforeunload is getting triggered and session gets invalidated.

Please let me know If some body knows the solution for this problem.

```
/*JS code begins here*/

/*Global js variable to decide whether to call session invalidate function*/

    var validNavigation = false;
        //Called when page loads initially
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
           //Call to wireupEvents
        wireUpEvents();

                });
        //Function called when the page loads
            function wireUpEvents() {


            window.onbeforeunload= function() {





                if (!validNavigation) {
                           /*This JS function calls my managed bean method to invalidate session.*/
                    windowCloseJsFunction();
                }
            }


        // Attach the event keypress to exclude the F5 refresh
            jQuery(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 116) {

                    alert('116');
                    validNavigation = true;
                }
            });

            // Attach the event click for all links in the page
            jQuery("a").bind("click", function() {
                alert('click a');
                validNavigation = true;

            });

            // Attach the event submit for all forms in the page
            jQuery("form").bind("submit", function() {
                alert('form');
                validNavigation = true;
            });

            // Attach the event click for all inputs in the page
            jQuery("input[type=submit]").bind("click", function() {
                alert('input');
                validNavigation = true;
            });
        //Attach button click for all inputs in the page
            jQuery("input[type=button]").bind("click", function() {
          validNavigation = true;
        });

        }

    /*JS code ends here*/
```

Comment: Why do you need to invalidate the session at first? Why the timeout solution doesn't work for you?

Comment: Session timout is set to 30 mins,  but before that say if I close the browser by any chance then I need to wait for 30 mins to relogin as I am maintaining cuncurrent session to 1

Comment: "then I need to wait for 30 mins to relogin as" --- why is that? If that's the issue - just keep the latest session. Solve the root of the issue, not the consequences.

Comment: In my application through spring security the maximum session is set to 1 , so at any time there can be one session per user. If I close the browser , then session will not be invalidated and i cant relogin.

Comment: so implement it in a way that the old one is dropped and another one is created. Otherwise you're creating huge headache for users for no practical reason.

Comment: Will you please give some more light on overriding sessions ?

Comment: Barely - I'm not a Java programmer. But the thing is- your current workflow looks terrible from user convenience perspective